# Android canvas. How to set circles at random position?

Tags: java, android, canvas, collision-detection

Below code generated and save position x y to HashMap and check collision two circles;

```
        HashMap<Integer, Float> posX = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Integer, Float> posY = new HashMap<>();

        int numberOfCircle = 8;

        for(int i=0; i < numberOfCircle; i ++){

           // boolean flag = false;
            while (true){

                float x =random.nextInt(width - raduis/2) + raduis/2f;
                float y =random.nextInt(height - raduis/2) + raduis/2f;

                if(!posX.containsValue(x) && !posY.containsValue(y)){

                    if(i == 0){

                        posX.put(i, x);
                        posY.put(i, y);
                        break;
                    }
                    if(i > 0){

                      double distance = Math.sqrt(((posX.get(i - 1) - x) * (posX.get(i - 1) - x)) + ((posY.get(i - 1) - y) * ( posY.get(i - 1) - y)));

                        if (distance > raduis+raduis) {

                            posX.put(i, x);
                            posY.put(i, y);
                            Log.d(TAG, i + " xPos=" + posX.get(i) + " yPos=" + posY.get(i) + " distance=" + distance);
                            break;
                        }

                        if(numberOfCircle == posX.size()) break;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

This code work only if circle count=2; But when circle count > 2 i have collision; How to check current generated position for each in HashMap?

For example:
xPos = {5, 10, 3}
yPos = {10, 33, 5}

generated position x=6, y=10;
calculate distance between x=6, y=10 with all positions in Map. If distance < radius+radius generate new position while distance > radius+radius;

Update ========================>

My code work like 
[image]

I want like this

[image]

output: distance equal between current generated position(X, Y) and previous position(X, Y). I want to check  between current generated x, y with all added positons in HashMap.

```
D/DEBUG DATA ===>: 1 xPos=432.0 yPos=411.0 distance=390.6430595825299
D/DEBUG DATA ===>: 2 xPos=316.0 yPos=666.0 distance=280.1446055165082
D/DEBUG DATA ===>: 3 xPos=244.0 yPos=83.0 distance=587.4291446634223
D/DEBUG DATA ===>: 4 xPos=214.0 yPos=551.0 distance=468.96055271205915
D/DEBUG DATA ===>: 5 xPos=76.0 yPos=1011.0 distance=480.2540994098853
D/DEBUG DATA ===>: 6 xPos=289.0 yPos=868.0 distance=256.55019002136794
D/DEBUG DATA ===>: 7 xPos=494.0 yPos=988.0 distance=237.53947040439405
```

P.s Sorry so poor English.

Comment: Why are x/y `float` when they are calculated as `int` initially (by random)? And you truncate that in weird way, you can end with `x` a tiny bit beyond `width` in extreme case. (`width: 400, raduis: 1 -> nextInt(400) -> 399 -> 399 + 0.5f = 399.5f` is out of [r/2, 399] range) ... I think you did want `x = nextInt(width - radius) + radius*0.5f`, which will produce random numbers in [r/2, width-r/2] range.  Also can you explain why `if(!posX.containsValue(x) && !posY.containsValue(y)){`? So no circle can have identical x or y position to any toher circle?

Comment: So did you tried to use my answer, or what is status of this Q?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something closer to this will work? I'm not entirely sure if it's what you want or if it will help, but I did a quick rewrite for clarity.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> posX = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Integer, Integer> posY = new HashMap<>();

final int circlesToPlace = 8;

for(int i = 0 ; i < circlesToPlace ; i++){

    // boolean flag = false;
     while (true){
         final int x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt((radius/2f), width + 1);
         final int y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt((radius/2f), height + 1);

        // Iterate over all other positions to ensure no circle intersects with
        // the new circle.
        for (int index = 0 ; index < posX.size() ; index++) {
            // Calculate distance where d = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)
            final int otherX = posX.get(index);
            final int otherY = posY.get(index);

            int differenceX = otherX - x;
            differenceX *= differenceX;

            int differenceY = otherY - y;
            differenceY *= differenceY;

            final double distance = Math.sqrt(differenceX + differenceY);


            if (distance > (radius * 2)) {
                posX.put(i, x);
                posY.put(i, y);
                Log.d(TAG, i + " xPos=" + posX.get(i) + " yPos=" + posY.get(i) + " distance=" + distance);
                break;
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ty for replay. While never end.

Answer (score 0):

My variant. You don't need to do sqrt to compare distance, you can instead square the constant (`d2` in my case).

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int numberOfCircle = 8, width = 400, height = 300;
    int diameter = 51;
    final float radius = diameter * 0.5f;
    final float d2 = diameter * diameter;

    List<Float> posX = new ArrayList<>(numberOfCircle);
    List<Float> posY = new ArrayList<>(numberOfCircle);

    while (posX.size() < numberOfCircle) {  // till enough generated

        // generate new coordinates
        float x = random.nextInt(width - diameter) + radius;
        float y = random.nextInt(height - diameter) + radius;

        System.out.printf("Generated [%3.3f, %3.3f] ... ", x, y);

        // verify it does not overlap/touch with previous circles
        int j = 0;
        while (j < posX.size()) {
            float dx = posX.get(j) - x, dy = posY.get(j) - y;
            float diffSquare = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
            if (diffSquare <= d2) break;
            ++j;
        }

        // generate another pair of coordinates, if it does touch previous
        if (j != posX.size()) {
            System.out.println("collided.");
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println("added.");

        // not overlapping/touch, add as new circle
        posX.add(x);
        posY.add(y);
    } // while (posX.size() < numberOfCircle)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve like this

```
private class MyView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener{

    List<Circle> randomCircles = new ArrayList<>();
    int radius = new Circle().getRadius();
    int randomCircleCount = 3;
    Random random = new Random();

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Integer width = canvas.getWidth();
        Integer width = canvas.getWidth();
        Integer height = canvas.getHeight() - (radius);
        // Integer height = canvas.getHeight()/2 + canvas.getHeight();

        ///randomCircles.clear();

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);

        Paint paintT = new Paint();
        paintT.setTextSize(18f);
        paintT.setAntiAlias(true);
        paintT.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        while(randomCircles.size() < randomCircleCount){
            randomCircle(width, height);
        }

        for(int i=0; i < randomCircleCount; i ++){

            Circle circle = randomCircles.get(i);

            float curPosX = randomCircles.get(i).getCx().floatValue();
            float curPosY = randomCircles.get(i).getCy().floatValue();

            int r = random.nextInt(256);
            int g = random.nextInt(256);
            int b = random.nextInt(256);

            paint.setARGB(175, 77, 2, 200);
            //if(r != 0 && g != 0 && b != 0)  paint.setARGB(255, r, g, b);


            canvas.drawCircle(curPosX, curPosY, radius, paint);
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            String text = "" +i;
            paintT.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawText(text, curPosX, curPosY, paintT);

            circle.update(width, height);
            //Log.d(TAG,  "REDRAW");
        }

        ///invalidate();
        postInvalidateDelayed(100);

    }

    private void randomCircle(int width, int height) {

        double x = getPosX(width, radius);
        double y = getPosY(height,radius);


        boolean hit = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < randomCircles.size(); i++) {

            Circle circle = randomCircles.get(i);

            double dx = circle.getCx() - x;
            double dy = circle.getCy() - y;

            int r = circle.getRadius() + radius;
            if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= r * r) {
                Log.d(TAG, "dx=" + dx + " dy=" + dy);
                hit = true;
            }
        }

        if (!hit) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Here!!!!!");
            randomCircles.add(new Circle(x, y));
        }

    }

private Float getPosX(Integer width, Integer radius){
        return random.nextInt(width - radius/2) + radius/2f;
    }
    private Float getPosY(Integer height, Integer radius){
        return random.nextInt(height - radius/2) + radius/2f;
    }
```

Comment: `random.nextInt(width - radius/2) + radius/2f;`, for example with `width=1000, radius = 99`, will produce values from `49.5` to `999.5` (so if screen coordinates are from `0` to `999`, you may get the circle centre outside of screen space).